# Prepend new vim buffer with 2 new lines

Tags: linux, email, vim, text-editors, mutt

I am using vim from mutt to reply to my emails and in the .muttrc I have the follow specified:

```
set editor= 'vim +1 -c "set textwidth=72" -c "set wrap" -c "set nocp" -c "set spell"'
```

I want to be able to add 2 new lines on top of the reply buffer so that I don't have to add them to every new reply.

So how do I prepend a new buffer from the launch options/commands?

Also, any other vim editor commands are welcome that would be useful in this situation : )

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be better to set up a skeleton file (:help skeleton), but you can do:

```
 vim -c 'call append(0, ["foo", "bar"])'
```

to insert the two lines "foo" and "bar" at the first two lines of the new buffer.

Comment: So, by inference, you could add two blank lines by removing the 'foo' and 'bar'?

Comment: If merely adding blank lines, I would prefer romainl's suggestion: `vim -c 'normal 2O' +3`

Answer (score 0):

```
vim -c "set textwidth=72" -c "set wrap" -c "set nocp" -c "set spell" -c "normal 2O" +3
```

should work. That's a Capital O, not a zero, by the way.